# how use POST instead GET on typehead.js?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use POST instead of GET in typeahead plugin, I changed the type to POST using the method "beforeSend", but I don't know how to change the "XHR data" to: {query: "what was typed"}.

my code:

```
$('#myinput').typeahead({
    name: "myinput",
    remote: {
        url: 'clients.php',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings) {
            settings.type = 'POST'
        }
    }
})
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the solution here: [typeahead.js remote beforesend post data issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874121/typeahead-js-remote-beforesend-post-data-issue#comment28090793_18874121)

Basically you need to change `settings.data`, but also set `settings.hasData` to `true`.