# Using HTTP POST with typeahead js and bloodhound js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

By default, bloodhound.js will query via HTTP GET, but that leaves you vulnerable to [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/). Since I have sensitive information that I want to load into typeahead, HTTP GET leaves me vulnerable. There used to be an option for picking post (as shown here: [typeahead.js remote beforesend post data issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874121/typeahead-js-remote-beforesend-post-data-issue)), but that doesn't work with the latest version (v.0.11.1).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46927923/3966458 without ajax

Answer (score 17):

It took me lots of heartache and experimenting to get this. In the latest version (v.0.11.1) there is a `transport` function option, you can use this to delegate to whatever you want (websockets, or plain old `$.ajax` with a post).

```
var accountBloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
        url: '/account/search#%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        transport: function (opts, onSuccess, onError) {
            var url = opts.url.split("#")[0];
            var query = opts.url.split("#")[1];
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: "search=" + query,
                type: "POST",
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError,
            })
        }
    }
});

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'best-pictures',
    display: 'value',
    source: accountBloodhound 
}).bind('typeahead:select', function (ev, suggestion) {
    console.log('Selection: ' + suggestion);
});
```

Comment: your heartache has paid-off ;)

Comment: In your example transport takes the following (opts, onSuccess, onErro), where are they initialized. I am struggling hard to understand how onSuccess binds to source.

Comment: @inlokesh - opts is an object that is created by typeahead and handed to your transport function. You can set a breakpoint/debugger command within the transport  function. onSuccess and onError are just callback functions to use/call when the method is successful or errored. You can see that I just pass them off wholesale to my jquery ajax call, but you could call them if you so desired.

Comment: Thank you for this lifesaver!

Comment: Hi @viggity, this is very helpful. But can I also pass an api-key here?

Answer (score 3):

This [Link](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/907) will help

```
var searchAuto = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('word'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: base_url + 'ajax/get_words',
        prepare: function (q, rq) {

            $(".typeahead-loader").show();

            rq.data = {
                q: $("#SearchData").val(),
                // source: 'S01',
                searchtype: $("#Searchtype").val(),
                language: $("#language").val(),
                author: $("#author").val(),
                raag: $("#raag").val(),
                page_from: $("#page_from").val(),
                page_to: $("#page_to").val()
            };
            return rq;
        },
        transport: function (obj, onS, onE) {

            $.ajax(obj).done(done).fail(fail).always(always);

            function done(data, textStatus, request) {
                // Don't forget to fire the callback for Bloodhound
                onS(data);
            }

            function fail(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Don't forget the error callback for Bloodhound
                onE(errorThrown);
            }

            function always() {
                $(".typeahead-loader").hide();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

if you console.log the obj, i.e, first param, you will get

[image]

and you can easily override the `type` in `obj`

`obj.type = 'POST'`

Hope this helps...